# Traverse ROWS using jquery

Tags: jquery, traversal

I have dynamically generated rows in my webpage, as shown below (by data view webpart/sharepoint)
[image]

I have a radio buttons in all the TR element where CLASS= ROWSALL.

I need to traverse up till ID not equal to group1

So , RADIO button from highlighted row will be clicked, I need to count how many rows before this rows are available till ID =GROUP1 (In this case its 3)

[image]

I can come to parent TR of radio button , by using this.CLOSEST(‘.rowsALL’), but how to traverse through those three TR elements ? (Three is not fixed number, there can be any number of TR between TR with ID group1)

Please help.

EDit: I understand we should not have same IDs , but this is autogenerated by sharepoint dataview webpart, where we do not have control. I should try some of the suggestion and update answer.

Comment: As you can see in your first snapshot, 2 TRs having same id `group1`, which is not valid. Kindly do the structure correct and share your jquery code to help you.

Comment: I understand we should not have same IDs , but this is autogenerated by sharepoint dataview webpart, where we do not have control.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parents('tr').eq(0),
        $siblings = $parent.prevUntil('tr#group1');
        // or $siblings = $parent.siblings('.rowsAll:visible');
    console.log($siblings.length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use same id for differents elements. Instead you should use class.
Since your radio is inside a tr you must use patent then use prev till find a tr with group1 class look this

http://api.jquery.com/prev/

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest you to use different approach by using unique class name to the  element as you are using id multiple times.

First get the no. of rows and then subtract row number by 1 when id of the  element is 'group1', include this code in .each function. You will get the no. of rows till id 'group1'

Comment: Adding some code to demonstrate your approach would make this a much better answer.